# Map() в Python, или Почему итератор составленный мапом из введенных данных, работает в мапе но не в фильтре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю учебную задачу, и заметил, что, когда я создаю итератор из inputов следующим образом:

```
words = map(lambda x: input().lower(), range(int(input())))
```

, то список из этого итератора становится пустым, но если преобразовать все это с помощью функции list() на этапе присваивания, все работает. При этом, итератор без преобразования работает в другом map(), но не работает в filter(). С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Код:

```
words = map(lambda x: input().lower(), range(int(input())))
anagrams = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(list(x))), words))
word_groups = map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda w: tuple(sorted(list(w))) == x, list(words))), anagrams)
suitable = sorted(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, word_groups))
for s in suitable:
    print(" ".join(s))
```

Вторая строка работает, а третья - нет (но если преобразовать список все работает. Но в таком случае будет превышен лимит памяти)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что результат функции `map()` - это итератор. И пройдя по нему один раз - он закончится, и второй раз пройтись по нему не выйдет.
К примеру, для следующего кода:

```
m = map(int, ["0", "1", "2"])
print(list(m))
print(list(m))
```

Выведется:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[]
```

Comment: то есть нельзя использовать итератор больше одного раза?

Comment: @alex9127 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266180/can-iterators-be-reset-in-python

Comment: Нельзя. Т.к. он ничего не хранит, то просто не знает как вернуться на начало (а может такое даже в принципе невозможно, например, когда работа была с потоковыми данными). Тоже самое относится к генераторам.